# One table return value to insert another table as a column Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a Oracle trigger and I need to create column after insert rows to first table.

So.. In my scenario:

> When some record inserted into NEWS_TBL and i need to get that(in here i get it via last inserted record) and i need to get the NAME from the NEWS_TBL and returning value to NewsName variable and that returned value inserted to the NEWS_TYPE_TBL as a Column.

Below code is not working. can anyone pls give me a solution for this.

MyCode

```
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON NEWS.NEWS_FIRST 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

 NewsName varchar2(50); 

  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

      'select *
      from ( select a.NAME,a.ID, max(ID) over () as max_pk
      from NEWS_TBL a)
      where ID = max_pk
      RETURNING NAME INTO NewsName';

     'ALTER TABLE NEWS_TYPE_TBL ADD [NewsName] NUMBER(50) NULL'; 
     // I want to add returning ticket name to here from 1st query.

END trigNews;
/
```

Comment: Oracle or MS SQL Server ?

Comment: @Squirrel Oracle..........

Comment: May be you will redesign your application logic. DDL in triggers is not a good idea. Also I think that the use first select inside execute immediate is not a good idea too.
Also you have an wrong syntax of 'ALTER TABLE' statement.

Comment: You should not  create columns on the fly just like that. It will result in a pretty bad design.